# Converting CSS into Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I just found out about tailwind and absolutely loving it. However I am a bit stuck at this part. i dunno how to convert this bit of code into tailwindcss.

```
.link-underline {
border-bottom-width: 0;
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
background-size: 0 3px;
background-position: 0 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
transition: background-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.link-underline-black {
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
linear-gradient(#ec8200, #ec8200);
}
.link-underline:hover {
background-size: 100% 3px;
background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
before:bg-[#ec8200] before:rounded-bl before:-bottom-1.5 before:h-0.5 before:inset-x-0 before:absolute before:transform before:origin-left before:scale-x-0 before:transition-all before:duration-200 group-hover:before:scale-x-100;
```

any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You may want to look into tailwind's @apply property [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply)

Comment: I don't know why you're using before, scale, and absolute positioning in your attempt when that's not in the rules you shown us. You're also showing us more than one class, and aren't showing us how you're using them. But this should get you most of the way there: `transition-[background-size] bg-no-repeat ease-in-out duration-500 bg-left-bottom
bg-[length:0_3px] hover:bg-[length:100%_3px] border-b-0
bg-[linear-gradient(transparent,transparent),linear-gradient(#ec8200,#ec8200)]`